# Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Error decoding field Call

Tags: blockchain, substrate

When I want to use the method that is built in substrate based chain together with the custom type i get the following error:

```sh
2020-04-13 21:03:01 RPC-CORE: submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: 1002: Verification Error: Execution(ApiError("Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Error decoding field Call :: Poe.0")): RuntimeApi("Execution(ApiError(\"Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Error de
2020-04-13 21:03:01 DRR: Error: 1002: Verification Error: Execution(ApiError("Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Error decoding field Call :: Poe.0")): RuntimeApi("Execution(ApiError(\"Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: Error 
de
    at RpcCoder._checkError (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.js:83:13)
    at RpcCoder.decodeResponse (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.js:46:10)
    at WsProvider.value (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/ws/Provider.js:160:90)
    at W3CWebSocket.value [as onmessage] (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/ws/Provider.js:140:153)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:107:17)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /c/substrate-mvce/js-cli/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
```

Basically i am trying to use the Types that i define in the runtime pallet. The types are auto-generated from the metadata using the `@polkadot/typegen` package.

Full code for reproducing this is here https://github.com/woss/substrate-mvce

Comment: Can you please include a valid payload for the `Rule` type

Comment: the docs for this are https://substrate.dev/docs/en/conceptual/core/codec#data-structures

Comment: and here https://polkadot.js.org/api/examples/promise/90_typegen/

Comment: Hi woss, Can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Comment: i did. you can see my question there too.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the payload you are creating in TypeScript and sending to your Substrate node. The Substrate node does not seem to be able to parse the object.

I have found that you are definitely missing a property on the `Operation` type definition:

```
  Operation: {
    op: 'Vec<u8>',
    desc: 'Vec<u8>',
    hashAlgo: 'Vec<u8>',
    encodeAlgo: 'Vec<u8>',
    prefix: 'Vec<u8>',
    ops: 'Vec<Operation>',
  },
```

This is missing `hashBits`.

And looking further, it is not obvious that your pre-defined `photo` rules correctly satisfy the object definition defined by your runtime.

You need to check end to end that you have correctly defined these custom types and that the payload you are generating is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was the `hashBits` missing but that wasn't the solution. After adding the `hashBits` AND made modifications to the definition to have EXACTLY the same structure ( same position of the keys) as in the runtime, then it worked as it should. 
This means following

```rust
pub struct Rule {
  version: u32,
  description: Vec<u8>,
  creator: Vec<u8>,
  for_what: ForWhat,
  parent: Vec<u8>,
  ops: Vec<Operation>,
  build_params: Operation,
}
```

Must be this in the JS app

```
{
  Rule: {
    version: 'u32',
    description: 'Vec<u8>',
    creator: 'Vec<u8>',
    forWhat: 'ForWhat',
    parent: 'Vec<u8>',
    ops: 'Vec<Operation>',
    buildParams: 'Operation',
  }
}
```

If we would change the order of the keys in the definition it will fail.