# Extrinsic verification error:... FailedToConvertParameter "validate_transaction" Could not decode MultiAddress

Tags: rust, substrate

I am so sorry for the very newbie question...

My plan is to deploy the flippers contract to `substrate-node-template` ((https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template); specifically `tag = 'monthly-2021-05'`.

I copied what was on `canvas-node` (https://github.com/paritytech/canvas-node); anything `pallets_contracts*`,
that includes inside the `runtime` **lib.rs**:

```rust
parameter_types! {
  ...
  pub const MaxDepth: u32 = 100;
  pub const MaxValueSize: u32 = 16_384;
  pub const MaxCodeSize: u32 = 2 * 1024;
}

impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime { 
  ... 
  type MaxDepth = MaxDepth;
  type MaxValueSize = MaxValueSize;
  type MaxCodeSize = MaxCodeSize;
}
...

impl_runtime_apis! {
  impl pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi< 
   Block,
   AccountId, 
   Balance, 
   BlockNumber, 
   Hash
> for Runtime {
  ... 
}
```

and the `node` **rpc.rs**

```rust
io.extend_with(
    ContractsApi::to_delegate(Contracts::new(client.clone()))
);
```

The project will build, but when I click the `SignAndSubmit` button on [canvas-ui](https://paritytech.github.io/canvas-ui), a warning would appear:[image]

```
 RPC-CORE: submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: ApiError(FailedToConvertParameter { function: "validate_transaction", parameter: "tx", error: Error { cause: None, desc: "Could not decode `MultiAddress`, variant doesn\'t exist" } }): RuntimeApi, Execution failed: ApiError, FailedToConvertParameter { function: \"validate_transaction\", parameter: \"tx\", error: Error { cause: None, desc: \"Could not decode `MultiAddress`, variant doesn\\\'t exist\" } }
```

What did I do wrong? Or is Canvas-UI only works with Canvas-Node?

Comment: The custom substrate node you are using has types that the canvas UI doesn't know how to use. You need to let the JS API know about these manually, here is how: http://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend/

Comment: Here is a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194973/could-not-convert-parameter-tx-between-node-and-runtime-error-decoding-field

Comment: thanks @NukeManDan, i totally forgot about the polkadot.js, when i was trying out ink!. The ink! doc didn't mention it as well.

Anyway, if you could just transfer your comment as an "answer", i'll accept it. :) Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thanks to @NukeManDan, I went into Settings dropdown menu -> Developer in polkadot.js.org/apps, and changed to:

```json
{ 
  "Address": "MultiAddress", 
  "LookupSource": "MultiAddress" 
}
```

After that I just went in Developer dropdown menu -> Contracts , clicked ***Upload & deploy code*** button and selected my *.contract* file.

Yep, I stopped using the Canvas UI.